# The sum of a vertical section based on an two points in adjacent column

Tags: google-sheets

I need a function to add vertical cells based on input from another cell. For example, in the image, the input cell value is 12, so I the sum from zero to 12 of the highlighted blue section.

It will also start at zero but the value may change to 24, 36 etc.
[image]

Comment: Kindly add input table and expected output table as [**text table**](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/)(NOT as IMAGE) to the question. Adding such [md tables](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) greatly increases your chances of getting a elegant answer, as **it is easier to copy/paste**. If you share spreadsheets, your question maybe closed, as questions here must be [self contained](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455). [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), if you share Google files.

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See [How much research effort is expected of stackoverflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Answer (score 2):

You can use this formula with a helper cell :

```
=SUM(D4:INDIRECT("D"&B1+4))
```

Where--

- **D4** is the start range (starting 0 on PMT).
- **B1** is the helper cell/ end of range.

Kindly see the result below:
[image: Result]

You may refer to this link for more detailed explanation:

- [How To Sum A Dynamic Range: Google Sheets](https://scripteverything.com/how-to-sum-a-dynamic-range-google-sheets/)
  (I am not affiliated with this article, just found on google search)

Comment: If you want to recommend your own product or website, there are some [guidelines in place](/help/promotion) for doing so. Following them will help you avoid giving the impression that you're spamming. Please [edit] your post to explicitly state your affiliation. (If you're not actually affiliated, it may be worth mentioning that as well.)

Comment: Done editing. thanks for letting me know, will observe this moving forward @TheMaster